# Matplotlib line plot of data and projections missing a connection

Tags: python, pandas, database, matplotlib

I have the following dataframe:

```
df =pd.DataFrame( {'Area': ['Water', 'Water', 'Water', 'Water', 'Water'],
      'Year': ['2021', '2022', '2023', '2024', '2025'],
      'Amount': [1530.72, 1925.39, 1700.00, 2000.00, 2160.00],
      'Type': ['Actuals', 'Actuals', 'Actuals', 'Budget', 'Budget']})
```

I'd like to plot make a line plot with the Year on the X axis and the amount on the Y axis. I'd like the linetype for the 'Actuals' to be solid, and to be dotted for the 'Budget'.

I can almost do this, but I get I am missing the connection between 2023 and 2024.

```
plt.plot('Year', 'Amount', data=df[df['Type'] == 'Actuals'], marker='o', color='grey', linewidth=2)
plt.plot('Year', 'Amount', data=df[df['Type'] == 'Budget'], marker='o', color='grey', linewidth=2, linestyle='--')
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: matplotlib only draws lines between points. Here you've plotted two things, one from 2021 -> 2023 and one from 2024 -> 2025. Neither of these plots span the 2023-2024 year, hence no line. If you'd like a line, you could expand the `Budget` dataset to include the year `2023`, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @Gaberocksall in the comments, you are not asking `matplotlib` to draw line from `2023` to `2024`, which is why it doesn't exist in your plot.

You could get the result you want by expanding the `Budget` dataset to include the last line of the `Actuals` dataset:

```py
plt.plot('Year', 
    'Amount',
    data=df[df['Type'] == 'Actuals'],
    marker='o', color='grey', linewidth=2
)
plt.plot('Year',
    'Amount',
    data=pd.concat([df[df['Type']=='Actuals'].iloc[-1:], df[df['Type'] == 'Budget']]),
    marker='o', color='grey', linewidth=2, linestyle='--'
)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome. Thank you both. I had the same thought when I was in the shower this morning. Just tested and confirmed this is great. Thank you.